# Array of string from Arraylist of Arraylist

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to create an array of string from Arraylist of Arraylist.

Here is a code:

```
ArrayList MainList = new ArrayList();

ArrayList subList = new ArrayList();
subList.Add("A");
subList.Add("Apple");
MainList.Add(subList);

subList = new ArrayList();
subList.Add("B");
subList.Add("Banana");
MainList.Add(subList);

subList = new ArrayList();
subList.Add("C");
subList.Add("Caret");
MainList.Add(subList);

string[] AllList = { "A", "Apple", "B", "Banana", "C", "Caret" };
string[] OnlySome = { "Apple", "Banana", "Caret" };
```

I know we can do it using for each loop but how can I get AllList and OnlySome string array using LINQ Query ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: I'd also recommend you don't store your subLists as ArrayList. It seems more likely that you should be using something like: Dictionary<string,string>, List<FruitLookup>, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> or maybe a List<Tuple<string,string>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
var allList = 
    MainList.
        Cast<ArrayList>().
        SelectMany(a => a.Cast<string>()).
        ToArray();

var onlySome = 
    MainList.
        Cast<ArrayList>().
        Select(a => 
            a.Cast<string>().
                Skip(1).
                First()).
        ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `Cast` or `OfType` is better in cases like this.  I do prefer to `Cast` when casting, and to use `OfType` when I know the collection contains elements of that type and that they are all I care about.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what was the exact condition for OnlySome, therefore I thought 2 options,

- Select every other element (odd indexed, even location) `onlySome1`
- Select any string which has a length greater than 1 `onlySome2`

  ```
      var allList = (from al in MainList.ToArray()
                    from s in (al as ArrayList).ToArray()
                    select s as string).ToArray();

      // if you want to select every other element
      var onlySome1 = allList.Where((s, index) => index % 2 == 1).ToArray();

      // if you want to select all the strings with 2 or more characters.
      var onlySome2 = allList.Where(s => (s as string).Length > 1).ToArray();
  ```